# What is the analog of the 'controllerAs' directive's property in Angular 2 component?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I started to migrate one of my Angular 1 directives to the Angular 2 component.

The directive I am currently on has the `controllerAs: 'ctrl'` property and the directive's template uses `'ctrl.'` prefix when it access properties.

Looking at the [official ComponentMetadata doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html) I do not see any properties that can be used instead of this one.

Comment: each `Class` of component will have their context inside `this`, so you don't need to create controller alias here in `Angular2` you will directly get access to `this` context on HTML..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `controllerAs` in Angular 2. For example, given this controller class and template:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-a',
    template: `<div class="component-a">
                <div class="counter" (click)="increment()">Component A: {{counter}}</div>
              </div>`
})
export class ComponentA {

    counter = 0;

    increment() {
        this.counter += 1;
    }

}
```

In the method `increment()`, `this` is bounded to the  controller instance of that particular component itself. In the template, the counter can be accessed via `{{counter}}`.

As we can see there is no mechanism to name the controller because we can already access it using the default functionality.

You can either think that the `controllerAs` mechanism has been integrated in the default component functionality of Angular 2, or that functionality has been removed as its no longer needed, depending on how you look at it.