# If Angular2 doesn't have controllerAs, why is it recommended in Angular 1.5+?

Tags: angularjs

So in Angular 2 there is no controllerAs syntax, the properties of the components can be used directly in the template, e.g. like in this component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-a',
    template: `<div class="component-a">
                <div class="counter" (click)="increment()">Component A: {{counter}}</div>
              </div>`
})
export class ComponentA {

    counter = 0;

    increment() {
        this.counter += 1;
    }

}
```

(copied from [What is the analog of the 'controllerAs' directive's property in Angular 2 component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928467/what-is-the-analog-of-the-controlleras-directives-property-in-angular-2-compo))

This is like I started writing Angular 1.x < 1.5 since the beginning. Then "they" said "it's better to use the controllerAs syntax". Now I have `$ctrl.myThing` almost everywhere in my code. And even more, in some tutorials they suggest you to switch to controllerAs in order to get closer to Angular 2. But it seems to get farther away from the *syntax* at least?

I mean I get it, it's better when you use actual controllers and views and do stuff like:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{ title }}
  <div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl">
    {{ title }}
    <div ng-controller="YetAnotherCtrl">
      {{ title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I never did that anyways and used directives / components for all of those cases. So when my entire architecture in Angular 1.5+ is based on components anyways, then what's the advantage of controllerAs? I have an isolated scope anyways... So why not directly use no controllerAs, so it's the same syntax as Angular 2? I mean it's easy enough to migrate it as I could do a find and replace on all `$ctrl.` in the project, I just want to understand which benefits (if any) controllerAs brings in this scenario.

To make yet another example:
Is this

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.sayHello()">
    Hello {{$ctrl.somebinding}}
  </button>
```

prefered to this

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sayHello()">
    Hello {{somebinding}}
  </button>
```

as a template for an Angular 1.5+ **component** with an **isolated scope** and if so **why** since the syntax of the latter is actually closer to angular 2?

Comment: Have you seen anyone suggest controllerAs with component architecture in 1.5? We used controllerAs routinely until we started developing with a component mindset, and we haven't used controllerAs since.

Comment: I keep [this blog post](https://teropa.info/blog/2015/10/18/refactoring-angular-apps-to-components.html) on speed dial, but we don't use `controllerAs`, instead using the default `$ctrl` for each scope (which technically *is* an implementation of `controllerAs`).

Comment: Yes exactly, why is there `$ctrl.` everywhere in the template when in Angular 2 this is not required? Like you said, it technically is controllerAs.

Answer (score 0):

`controllerAs` should be used for directives and controllers, not components of course. (some libs like angular bootstrap, angular material, ui router were not migrated to 1.5-1.6 and still require controllers)

Guess most recommendation 'controllerAs' were written before Angular 1.5 - when there were no components.

I just meant that in component you have controller as $ctrl and there is no need in controllerAs syntax. If you interested why by default {{prop}} is not evaluated to controller property -- core angular service $parse worked with scope in 1.4- so when they added components they obviously could not change this. Otherwise, all written code for previous angular version vould stop working.

Comment: But it's even the angular default with `$ctrl` for components, see here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component. How come you say it's not supposed to be used for components?